# Solving a system of linear non-autonomous ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following system of linear differential equations in $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$:

\begin{align}
y'_1(t)=a_1(t)+a_2(t)y_1(t)+a_3(t)y_2(t),\\
y'_2(t)=b_1(t)+b_2(t)y_1(t)+b_3(t)y_2(t),
\end{align}
together with two boundary conditions, say $y_1(0)=y_1^*$ and $y_2(0)=y_2^*$.

If I am not mistaken, this is a system of linear, non-autonomous ordinary differential equations. I know how to solve this if the coefficients $a$ and $b$ are independent of time, and also how to solve a single non-autonomous ODE (so if $a_3=0$ or $b_2=0$). However, online and in my textbooks I cannot find how to solve the system of ODE's if the coefficients are time-varying.

Does anyone have an idea how to proceed, or references? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When the coefficients are time dependent there is no 'nice' general solution. You can formulate the homogeneous problem as a matrix equation $\mathbf{y}'(t)=A(t)\mathbf{y}(t)$. The formal solution is a time ordered exponential $\mathbf{y}(t)=\mathcal{T}\exp \left(\int\limits^t_0 dt' A(t') \right) \mathbf{y}(0)$. If $A$ commutes at different times, the time ordering is irrelevant and the formal solution is a bit nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general there is no "closed-form" solution.  The homogeneous case ($a_1 = b_1 = 0$) can be written in terms of a "time-ordered exponential".  Solutions of the non-homogeneous case can then be found as integrals involving the time-ordered exponential.